# How do I obtain a geonames API key

Tags: geonames, geokit

My apologies for the basic question, I am just starting to use Geonames.

The Ruby geokit gem contains the following instruction for using Geonames:

```
# To use this service either free or premium, you must register a key.
# See http://www.geonames.org
Geokit::Geocoders::GeonamesGeocoder.key = 'KEY'
```

I have registered on the Geonames site, but I cannot find out how to generate an API key for myself.  I have looked all over the geonames web site but cannot find a page which appears to do this.

It must be possible somehow.  Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4):

Just register for the free service from [the geonames.org login page](http://www.geonames.org/login) Geonames use the `username` parameter to count request already sent.

Since you have limited credit remember to setup request caching before going to production.

Answer (score 4):

The key is the **username**.

For those who are looking to register and use the [Geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit) gem:

- Register to get a Geonames username ([link](http://www.geonames.org/login))
- Confirm your account from your email address.
- Enable free web services in your account page ([link](https://www.geonames.org/manageaccount))
- Add your username to Geokit: `Geokit::Geocoders::GeonamesGeocoder.key = 'username'`. If you are using rails, you can add that line of code to an initializer.

The [Timezone](https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone) gem is also handy to lookup time zones from coordinates retrieved through Geokit, and it also supports Geonames:

```
Timezone::Lookup.config(:geonames) do |c|
  c.username = 'username'
end
```